# How to align div to the bottom of another div in HTML?

Tags: html, css, alignment

How do I align div to the bottom of another div in HTML?
And why it doesn't work?
HTML:

```
<div id="big">
      <div class="small">1</div>
      <div class="small">2</div>
      <div class="small">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#big {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}

.small {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: its unclear who has to be on the bottom of who, but if anyones gonna stay on the bottom, vertical-align: bottom, should do it

Comment: Could you post an image showing your desired outcome?

Comment: Please describe your requirements better. Its unclear quite how you are trying to align stuff. [This fiddle shows vertical and horizontal blocks](http://jsfiddle.net/55bd8eng/1/) are either of them closer to what you're after?

Comment: Why you are not showing as in an simple Paint images ... Your question is hard to understand as you describe it.

Comment: From your comment on the answer by dragos.bd, I assume you want something along these lines. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEWBGG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is unclear but do you mean like this?..

[image]

```css
#big {
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background-color: red; margin: 10px; width: 800px; height: 300px;
}

.small {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: blue; 
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
      <div class="small">1</div>
      <div class="small">2</div>
      <div class="small">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, the whole day I've tried dozens of solutions and none of them worked...

Comment: If only your search skills were as honed your question writing ones ;)

Answer (score 3):

This will work:
http://jsfiddle.net/4f4ejwr0/5/

```css
#big {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}
#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.small {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="small">1</div>
    <div class="small">2</div>
    <div class="small">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: These are all stacked on top of each other in the bottom left. Are you sure this is what the OP wants?

Comment: Ok....it works...but how can I keep the elements inside this bottom div horizontally centered?? They were at the center with div's text-align before this solution, now they aren't anymore....

Answer (score 0):

is this what youre looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/94/

should be changed to

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS Class:

```
bottom:0 !important;
```

and remove the position portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    #big {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 150px; //new line
}

.small {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    position: relative; // new line
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Live [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rk1hk11s/)

Update: This is ok ? [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f4ejwr0/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still doesn't work. The small blue divs are still at the top of the big red div, I want them to be at the bottom of the big div.
updated CSS:
#big {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
}

.small {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}